# Can't get stdout/stderr from (Python) subprocess.check_output()

Tags: python, git, subprocess, stdout, stderr

I'm trying to get the message from a `git add` command, to print to a log file later on.

```
import subprocess
import os

filename = 'test.txt'

# Add changes
add_cmd = """git add "%s" """ % filename
os.system(add_cmd)
a = subprocess.check_output(add_cmd, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

The `os.system()` call shows in screen:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

which is correct, since this folder is not a `git` repo.

But the `subprocess.check_output()` call fails with:

```
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    a = subprocess.check_output(add_cmd, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'git add "test.txt" ' returned non-zero exit status 128
```

Why am I not able to catch the error message with `subprocess.check_output()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the documenation for [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

> If the return code was non-zero it raises a `CalledProcessError`. The `CalledProcessError` object will have the return code in the `returncode` attribute and any output in the `output` attribute.

`git add` returns a non-zero exit code when there is an error condition. Catch that exception, your output is there:

```
try:
    a = subprocess.check_output(add_cmd, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as cpe:
    print cpe.output
```

Demo:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> import os
>>> filename = 'test.txt'
>>> add_cmd = """git add "%s" """ % filename
>>> try:
...     a = subprocess.check_output(add_cmd, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
... except subprocess.CalledProcessError as cpe:
...     print cpe.output
...
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

>>> cpe.returncode
128
```

You probably don't need to use `shell=True`; pass in your arguments as a *list* instead and they'll be executed without an intermediary shell. This has the added advantage you don't need to worry about properly escaping `filename`:

```
add_cmd = ['git', 'add', filename]
try:
    a = subprocess.check_output(add_cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as cpe:
    print cpe.output
```