# Getting messages of subprocess from stdout or stderr

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Temporarily I've changed my proxy configuration to induce below error on `cmd.exe`...

```
C:\Users\su79e\abs_engine>C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Scripts/conda create --name test python=3.5

Fetching package metadata ...

# After 5~10 seconds

CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url <https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: None

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
ProxyError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.continuum.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001DBCA650AC8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)))",),)
```

Well that's good. On the other hand, I wanted to catch those error messages using subprocess module like the code below.

**test.py**

```
with subprocess.Popen("C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Scripts/conda create -y --name test python=3.5",
                      universal_newlines=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
    # out, err = proc.communicate()
    # logger.info(out)
    # logger.info(err)
    while proc.poll() is None:
        logger.info(proc.stdout.readline())
        # logger.info(proc.stderr.readline())
```

Although I can "see" full messages on `cmd.exe` while running `test.py`,
but logger only captures like below...

```
test.py:104 - INFO - 2017-09-11 22:16:29,858 - Fetching package metadata ...
test.py:104 - INFO - 2017-09-11 22:16:29,858 -
```

In spite of while loop, it only catches messages right before error. Am I missing something? I've already checked many answers on Stackoverflow and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38925806/cant-get-stdout-stderr-from-python-subprocess-check-output/38925818#38925818) seems quite close to my issue, but there was no fortune. Any advice will be very helpful to me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely that's because you only redirect stdout to a pipe. You would also have to redirect stderr (see the documentation for Popen):

```
subprocess.Popen("C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Scripts/conda create -y --
name test python=3.5", universal_newlines=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
```

(You're missing the `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` here)

But if you redirect both stdout and stderr to a pipe, on windows you'll need to run an additional thread so you can read from both pipes at the same time.

If you do it in a single thread and block on reading stdout while a lot of data is dumped to the stderr pipe, you might hang forever because the stderr pipe buffer would fill up and block the process that writes to stderr, which would mean that both processes would be deadlocked, one waiting for the stderr buffer to become empty, the other for the stdout buffer to fill up with a line of output.

On Linux you could use the select call to select a pipe that has data available to read from, but that only works for sockets on Windows.

Another solution that doesn't require threads might be to redirect your command's stderr into stdout before piping it to your python process. You won't be able to tell which bytes originally went to stdout and which ones to stderr, but depending on your use case, that might not be important to know.